# Where is the "Intersection" tool located in QGIS 3?

Tags: polygon, qgis-3, line, intersection

I would like to generate the intersection between lines and polygons lines and polygon in QGIS 3 and extract the id number for each line. I would like to assign a red color to the resulting lines automatically. I would also like to export the results to [MS Excel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel) format.

Where is the intersection tool located in QGIS 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The intersection tool is located under Vector --> Geoprocessing Tools --> Intersection.

[image]

2. You can assign a color to the resulting layer after processing
3. You can export your data to MS Excel XLSX by right clicking on the layer --- > Export ---> Save features As then choosing MS Office Open XML Spreadsheet.

   [image]
4. If you need all the above tasks to be processed automatically, you can create a model using the "Graphic Modeller" under "Processing (Menu ---> Graphic Modeller)"

[image]

[image]